# JIRA - Revision Fix, Work Start and Resolve Issue

Tags: jira

Do you all add revision fixed to your custom fields?

And what is the point of have `Work Start`? I thought `resolve issue` is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

We add the revision planned to fix and the revision fixed. Using the estimated times allows us to plan a certain chunk of work for the next release.

Indicating Work Started shows what each person in the team is working on currently. We're not as rigorous with the time tracking but this gives an indication of progress through each task for long tasks and lets you estimate the remaining time.

Answer (score 0):

We use revision fixed. Makes producing change logs etc much easier.

Never used the work tracking at all. Always just seems like too much hassle, and the teams we've been on we haven't needed to track it that closely. It's different than resolving an issue - that just marks that something is complete. Work start tracks how much time was spent, and if someone is still looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Revision fixed is very useful when you want to track progress of coming releases, and to see which issues has been fixed in previous releases. The road-map view displays all versions with their associated issues.